# Pandas timezone - how to check if it is not defined for a whole column?

Tags: pandas, datetime, timestamp, timezone

To check if a timezone is not defined for the first row of a "timestamp" column in a pandas Series I can query `.tz` for a single element with:

```py
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2/2/2002', periods=10, freq='M'))
assert dates.iloc[0].tz is None
```

Do I have a way to check if there are elements where the timezone is defined, or even better, a way to list all the timezones in the whole series, without looping through its elements, such as:

```py
dates.iloc[5] = dates.iloc[5].tz_localize('Africa/Abidjan')
dates.iloc[7] = dates.iloc[7].tz_localize('Africa/Banjul')

zones = []
for k in range(dates.shape[0]):
    zones.append(dates.iloc[k].tz)
print(set(zones))
```

?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the time zone setting of a datetime Series using the [dt accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html), i.e. `S.dt.tz`. This will raise `ValueError` if you have multiple time zones since the datetime objects will then be stored in an object array, as opposed to a datetime64 array if you have only one time zone or `None`. You can make use of this to get a solution that is a bit more efficient than looping every time:

```
import pandas as pd
# tzinfo is None:
dates0 = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2/2/2002', periods=10, freq='M'))
# one timezone:
dates1 = dates0.dt.tz_localize('Africa/Abidjan')
# mixed timezones:
dates2 = dates0.copy()
dates2.iloc[5] = dates2.iloc[5].tz_localize('Africa/Abidjan')
dates2.iloc[7] = dates2.iloc[7].tz_localize('Africa/Banjul')

for ds in [dates0, dates1, dates2]:
    try:
        zones = ds.dt.tz
    except ValueError:
        zones = set(t.tz for t in ds.values)
    
    print(zones)
    
# prints
None
Africa/Abidjan
{None, <DstTzInfo 'Africa/Banjul' GMT0:00:00 STD>, <DstTzInfo 'Africa/Abidjan' GMT0:00:00 STD>}
```